# What's the meaning of "piqueur" and "game" in the following context?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

> In the grey dawn the **game** was turned and the branch broken by our best **piqueur**. A rare day's hunting lies before us.

Google says **piqueur** is a French word means whipper in English. But I still can't understand the words **piqueur**  and **game** here.

I find in old English , **game** has the meaning of wild animals or birds that people hunt for sport or food. It's uncountable. Probably it's correct for this context.

[Edit]
More specific context of this sentence are:

> And then, if he lived near to a cover, there would be the more hares and rabbits to eat out his harvest, and the more hunters to tramper it down. My lord has a new horn from England. He has laid out seven francs in decorating it with silver and gold, and fitting it with a silken leash to hang about his shoulder. The hounds have been on a pilgrimage to the shrine of Saint Mesmer, or Saint Hubert in the Ardennesm, or some other holy intercessor who has made a speciality of the health of hunting-dogs. **In the grey dawn the game was turned and the branch broken by our best piqueur. A rare day's hunting lies before us.** Wind a jolly flourish, sound the bien-aller with all your lungs. Jacques must stand by, hat in hand, while the quarry and hound and huntsman sweep across his field, and a year's sparing and labouring is as though it had not been.——*The Essential Travel Writings*, Robert Louis Stevenson

Comment: Did you look up [piqueur](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/piqueur) in an English dictionary? The French meaning isn't that helpful.

Comment: @PeterShor interesting...a whipper in the sense of someone that whips away the brush to clear a path.

Comment: @Rowan "piqueur" in French also carries the meaning, "an attendant directing the hounds in a hunt." http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/piqueur

Comment: @Elian: which is also the relevant [English](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/piqueur) meaning.

Comment: @PeterShor Indeed.

Comment: So, a master of hounds maybe the correct meaning? If so, I need help in the whole meaning of this sentence. Does this means that "In the early morning, wild animals was move around and the master of hounds clear the path to hunt“？

Comment: @Elian I directly use google translate. I thought google may handle well with a single word.

Comment: @Rowan Not a "whipper" actually, but a "whipper-in" http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/translate/english-french/whipper-in

Comment: 'Game' in the sense of 'meat of wild animals' is in current usage, at least in the UK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My reconstruction has grown too long for a comment, So here goes

> In the grey dawn **the game** (the deer probably)
>   was **turned**  (startled out of hiding; various sites)
>   and the **branch** (thicket, brushwood, furze  Oxford Shorter)
>   **broken** (*burst open* ShorterOxford  **break** vb., VII 1))
>   by our best **piqueur** (*whipper-in* Elian and Oxford).
>   A rare day's hunting lies before us.

The deer will have been sleeping concealed in the thicket of brushwood.  The *piqueur's* job will be to know these hiding places; and the hunt starts when the deer breaks cover.

Comment: I just wondered why you deleted your comments:).

Comment: A thoroughly comprehensive answer, thank you all you guys.

Comment: @ Rowan they seemed to be duplicates: piquer = whipper in. Game = deer/quarry. And turned, broke, branch needed citations. BTW I still don't know how the raconteur fits into the story. Is his harvest destroyed? Does he join th hunt?